# How to make &auml; to ä in Java?

Tags: java, android

How can i replace "&A/auml;" to "Ä/ä" in an java string on android?

I tried [this solution][1], but it didn't work, because Eclipse says that "The import org.apache.commons.lang cannot be resolved".

Comment: yes you need to add lang jar form apache to your libs folder

Comment: And where do i get the jar?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to download the jar and put it into my libs folder. 
You can download it [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi). After you've successfully downloaded it you can import the StringEscapeUtils it with

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
```

To use it simply write this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(YourStringGoesHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the UTF code of the symbole(84)
in your string put \x84 to write the character

Comment: for the capital one,use 8e instead of 84

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode, in this instance for the upper \u00C4 and for the lower \u00E4 works.